# Is it possible to catch media stream URL of flash player using NPAPI functions?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, stream, media, npapi

I'm trying to make a video download panel for Chrome likes Real Player's one ( a DLL plugin )..
My question is :
    "Is it possible to use NPAPI functions such as
NPP_NewStream, NPP_StreamAsFile, NPP_DestroyStream... to catch the media stream URL of flash-player ? "
If not, then what part of NPAPI do I have to use ?

Comment: maybe your question is too general, you can ask more specific question by learning the Chrome plugin development guide. There you'll learn the technical stuff around the plugin development, which will allow you to be more precise in what you want to accomplish, and what to ask here.

Comment: Stop bumping your question. It'll get auto-bumped periodically, and if someone know the answer to your question they will help you. Bump in a few *days*, not every few minutes...

Comment: @ GMan - Save the Unicorns: ya. so sorry for that. Just because of my impatience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the NPAPI you can't magically spy on other components in the browser, the stream functions are for dealing with streams for your own plugin instance.

If the Flash player gives you access to the URL using scripting functions however, you can use the [scripting extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference:Scripting_plugins#The_API_extensions) to get it similar to how you'd retrieve it using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Now I am wondering how RealPlayer Plugin can do this magic :( It can catch any media stream request of any flash player, and display a bar at the top-right corner of the player, which will allow you to download the video. Like here : http://files.myopera.com/UenX/files/RealVideoDownloadPanel.jpg Then any suggestion for me? –

Comment: @user: That's a browser extension that provides the bar, not a plain NPAPI plugin. For Chrome see e.g. [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html#contentScripts).

Comment: @ Georg Fritzsche: Thanks, but i think it's really a NPAPI plugin, because when I disable all Chrome extension, it still work, still catch the link and show the bar and still call RealPlayer Downloader when I click on it. And I found the bar's image in a .DLL file of RealPlayer...