# How to catch a flash stream url from browser plugin

Tags: browser, firefox-addon, flash, npapi

My question has similar point like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980909/is-it-possible-to-catch-media-stream-url-of-flash-player-using-npapi-functions).

I’m wondering how I can catch a media URL which SWF loads from browser add-on. Let’s say YouTube flash player starts playing or loading some video (let it be via http) and I want to know that url. Just like browser plugins from [“RealDownloader”](http://www.real.com/realdownloader) and [“Moyea YouTube FLV Downloader”](http://www.flvsoft.com/download_flv/) does. I’m newbie with plugin development and flash and I want to know what technologies it may be. XPCOM, NPAPI, ActiveX, or simple API hooking. Any ideas how this may be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

NPAPI plugins typically ask the browser to load data for them, they don't do it themselves. This means that a browser extension can intercept these requests. This can be done for example by implementing a [content policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#Content_Policy). Requests initiated by a plugin will cause a `shouldLoad` call with type `OBJECT_SUBREQUEST`.

The simpler option is using [HTTP observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers) - but this way you won't recognize requests initiated by Flash, they will look just like any other request processed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug does that, and it's open source. Why not study it a little?

https://github.com/firebug/

Comment: Firebug is a huge bloated monster, "study it" is bad advise. For reference: Firebug uses HTTP observers (see my answer).

Comment: To ask for someone study a open-source project is never a bad advice, IMHO. also, the OP said he's newbie with plugin development.

Comment: Thank you Marcelo. I can look at FireBug but I don’t have a plenty of time to study it.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you only want to get the url from a single swf in a single website. for example if all you need are urls from that swf,you can keep only one instance of your browser open and use a tool to intercept its http requests.

Comment: Yes, I realized it could be a comment,thanks for reminding me.